# How to find all derived classes that are not abstract?

Tags: abstract-class, maui, derived-class

I'd like to find a way to filter out abstract classes so that I don't have to manually sift through sometimes 20 classes to find the few that are instantiable, if any at all.

I have gone to the maui .net API docs and looked at the list of derived classes from no particular class, which I have to manual open each one in a new tab and look to see.

Comment: You may want to add the framework or environment you are working in so that it can better reach knowledgeable users.

Comment: You may also want to add the programing language or tool you want to use to achieve this.